# CamScanner like crop and edge detection for document images in python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have few images with document like invoices, receipts and certificates. The documents in images are having various differences. Sizes of documents differ inside the image, sometimes only part of document is inside the image, sometimes the document is slightly crumpled, some images have perspective change in documents. I want to write a python script to get scanned image as a result like CamScanner which detects the edges of image perfectly even if image is cropped and only half of it is visible and then apply magic colour like filter which is my second priority. I have tried opencv methods and articles on the web but most of them assume to have 4 points but that does not happen when document is only half present in the image.

I would be grateful if you can provide more insights on this and discuss the possible solutions.

Comment: It's hard to even get a basic idea without seeing your images as they are currently and how you expect the result to look.